# How to call main Xml from Second Xml in android on button click?

Tags: android

I have two xml file. From first main Xml I am calling Second Xml file.

Second Xml file has some control and ‘Ok’ and ‘Cancel’ Button.

My question is how go first main when I click on ‘Ok’ or ’Cancel’ Button?

How should I write the code on ‘Ok’ or ’Cancel’ Button OnClickListener?

Thanks In Advance!

Comment: not getting can you please explain more ?

Answer (score 0):

My friend first of all i want to make you clear that `you can go from  one activity to the other`,or  you can `set an xml layout` on the current activity.However saying that you *

```
go from one xml to the other is wrong.
```

*

- **Now if you want to go back to the old activity** just use the `intent` in the similar way you  used to go from first to the second `activity` on your button `click`
- **and if you want to set the old layout** then call `setContentView()` in the `OnClickListener()` and pass the `layout's` id in `setContentView()` on your button `click`

> Thanks..